# I would like to merge three separate datasets to form one large dataset

Tags: r, merge, dataset

```
dataset_1 <- data.frame(
  Name = rep(c("Guyle", "Porter", "Frank", "Kojo"), c(5L, 5L, 5L, 1L)),
  Year = c(
    2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2014, 2015, 2016,
    2017, 2018, 2016
  ),
  Net_profit = c(
    2970L, 2798L, 2769L, 2686L, 2806L, 3096L, 2776L, 2993L, 2829L,
    3090L, 2536L, 2604L, 2984L, 2881L, 3100L, 2825L
  )
)

insurance <- data.frame(
  Names = c("Guyle", "Porter", "Frank"),
  `2014` = c(158, 154, 160),
  `2015` = c("169", "185", "NA"),
  `2016` = c("221", "NA", "NA"),
  `2017` = c("NA", "450", "691"),
  `2018` = c(200, 101, 321),
  check.names = FALSE
)

dataset3 <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Guyle", "Porter", "Frank"),
  Year = rep(2016, 3L),
  Risk_attitude = c("averse", "seeking", "seeking"),
  Acreage_ha = c(17.63, 26, 12),
  Adoption = c("late", "middle", "early")
)
```

I am expecting insurance as a column in dataset1 with the insurance amounts corresponding to the years in dataset1.
I am also expecting the columns in dataset 3 to be columns in dataset1. However, this data was collected only in 2016 so I would like to have the values under these columns correspond to the  only year=2016 in the dataset1`

I would like the resulting dataset to look like this with the empty columns filled with the right data(values) if matched.

```
overall_dataset <- data.frame(
  Name = rep(c("Guyle", "Porter", "Frank", "Kojo"), c(5L, 5L, 5L, 1L)),
  Year = c(
    2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2014, 2015, 2016,
    2017, 2018, 2016
  ),
  Net_profit = c(
    2970L, 2798L, 2769L, 2686L, 2806L, 3096L, 2776L, 2993L, 2829L,
    3090L, 2536L, 2604L, 2984L, 2881L, 3100L, 2825L
  ),
  insurance = rep("", 16L),
  Acreage = rep("", 16L),
  Risk_attitude = rep("", 16L)
)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! You have reproducible data, which is great, but it is a bit unclear what you want and what you start with. Can you provide a clear (input and) expected output?

Comment: I would like the resulting dataset to look like this:  overall_dataset<-data.frame(Name = c((rep('Guyle',5)), c(rep('Porter',5)), c(rep('Frank',5)), 'Kojo'),Year = c(rep(2014:2018,3),2016),Net_profit= c(sample(2500:3100, 16, replace=TRUE)), insurance=c(rep('',16)),Acreage=c(rep('',16)),Risk_attitude=c(rep('',16)))
overall_dataset

Comment: I am a bit confused, in the desired dataset you provided, all of your columns are blank. Do you simply want to initiate blank columns or do you want to fill those columns with relevant data, if matched?

Comment: I would like the columns to be filled with the correct data(values) if matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we try to bring these datasets together, we should do something about the mixed data types in the `insurance` data frame. Some year's are numeric and some are characters.

```r
insurance <- data.frame(
  Names = c("Guyle", "Porter", "Frank"),
  `2014` = c(158, 154, 160),
  `2015` = c("169", "185", "NA"),
  `2016` = c("221", "NA", "NA"),
  `2017` = c("NA", "450", "691"),
  `2018` = c(200, 101, 321),
  check.names = FALSE
)

library(tidyverse)

insurance %>%
  mutate(across(-Names, as.numeric)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Names, names_to = 'Year', values_to = 'insurance') 
#> Warning: There were 3 warnings in `mutate()`.
#> The first warning was:
#> ℹ In argument: `across(-Names, as.numeric)`.
#> Caused by warning:
#> ! NAs introduced by coercion
#> ℹ Run `dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings()` to see the 2 remaining warnings.
#> # A tibble: 15 × 3
#>    Names  Year  insurance
#>    <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1 Guyle  2014        158
#>  2 Guyle  2015        169
#>  3 Guyle  2016        221
#>  4 Guyle  2017         NA
#>  5 Guyle  2018        200
#>  6 Porter 2014        154
#>  7 Porter 2015        185
#>  8 Porter 2016         NA
#>  9 Porter 2017        450
#> 10 Porter 2018        101
#> 11 Frank  2014        160
#> 12 Frank  2015         NA
#> 13 Frank  2016         NA
#> 14 Frank  2017        691
#> 15 Frank  2018        321
```

Once that is sorted you can join the `insurance` and `dataset3` data frames to `dataset1` on the shared `Name` and `Year` variables.

```
dataset_1 %>%
  left_join(insurance %>%
              mutate(across(-Names, as.numeric)) %>%
              pivot_longer(-Names, names_to = 'Year', values_to = 'insurance') %>%
              mutate(Year = as.numeric(Year)), by = join_by(Year, Name == Names)) %>%
  left_join(dataset3, by = join_by(Year, Name))
#> Warning: There were 3 warnings in `mutate()`.
#> The first warning was:
#> ℹ In argument: `across(-Names, as.numeric)`.
#> Caused by warning:
#> ! NAs introduced by coercion
#> ℹ Run `dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings()` to see the 2 remaining warnings.
#>      Name Year Net_profit insurance Risk_attitude Acreage_ha Adoption
#> 1   Guyle 2014       2970       158          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 2   Guyle 2015       2798       169          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 3   Guyle 2016       2769       221        averse      17.63     late
#> 4   Guyle 2017       2686        NA          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 5   Guyle 2018       2806       200          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 6  Porter 2014       3096       154          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 7  Porter 2015       2776       185          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 8  Porter 2016       2993        NA       seeking      26.00   middle
#> 9  Porter 2017       2829       450          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 10 Porter 2018       3090       101          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 11  Frank 2014       2536       160          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 12  Frank 2015       2604        NA          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 13  Frank 2016       2984        NA       seeking      12.00    early
#> 14  Frank 2017       2881       691          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 15  Frank 2018       3100       321          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 16   Kojo 2016       2825        NA          <NA>         NA     <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The solution is relatively easy with functions in {tidyverse}:

```r
# data in the OP
dataset_1 <- data.frame(
  Name = rep(c("Guyle", "Porter", "Frank", "Kojo"), c(5L, 5L, 5L, 1L)),
  Year = c(
    2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2014, 2015, 2016,
    2017, 2018, 2016
  ),
  Net_profit = c(
    2970L, 2798L, 2769L, 2686L, 2806L, 3096L, 2776L, 2993L, 2829L,
    3090L, 2536L, 2604L, 2984L, 2881L, 3100L, 2825L
  )
)
insurance <- data.frame(
  Names = c("Guyle", "Porter", "Frank"),
  `2014` = c(158, 154, 160),
  `2015` = c("169", "185", "NA"),
  `2016` = c("221", "NA", "NA"),
  `2017` = c("NA", "450", "691"),
  `2018` = c(200, 101, 321),
  check.names = FALSE
)
dataset3 <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Guyle", "Porter", "Frank"),
  Year = rep(2016, 3L),
  Risk_attitude = c("averse", "seeking", "seeking"),
  Acreage_ha = c(17.63, 26, 12),
  Adoption = c("late", "middle", "early")
)
```

Solution codes:

```r
# here is the main code
library(tidyverse)
dataset_1 |> 
  left_join(
    insurance |> 
      pivot_longer(
        -Names, 
        names_to = "Year", 
        names_transform = as.numeric,
        values_to = "insurance", 
        values_transform = as.numeric
      ),
    by = join_by(Name == Names, Year)
  ) |> 
  left_join(dataset3, by = join_by(Name, Year))
#> Warning in .Primitive("as.double")(x, ...): NAs introduced by coercion

#> Warning in .Primitive("as.double")(x, ...): NAs introduced by coercion

#> Warning in .Primitive("as.double")(x, ...): NAs introduced by coercion
#>      Name Year Net_profit insurance Risk_attitude Acreage_ha Adoption
#> 1   Guyle 2014       2970       158          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 2   Guyle 2015       2798       169          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 3   Guyle 2016       2769       221        averse      17.63     late
#> 4   Guyle 2017       2686        NA          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 5   Guyle 2018       2806       200          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 6  Porter 2014       3096       154          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 7  Porter 2015       2776       185          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 8  Porter 2016       2993        NA       seeking      26.00   middle
#> 9  Porter 2017       2829       450          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 10 Porter 2018       3090       101          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 11  Frank 2014       2536       160          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 12  Frank 2015       2604        NA          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 13  Frank 2016       2984        NA       seeking      12.00    early
#> 14  Frank 2017       2881       691          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 15  Frank 2018       3100       321          <NA>         NA     <NA>
#> 16   Kojo 2016       2825        NA          <NA>         NA     <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can combine these with a little tweaking of the `insurance` data frame - most efficiently with the `dplyr` and `tidyr` libraries:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

insurance %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Names, names_to = "Year", values_to = "insurance",
               values_transform = list(insurance = as.numeric),
               names_transform = list(Year = as.numeric)) %>%
  rename(Name = Names) %>%
  left_join(dataset_1) %>%
  left_join(dataset3)
```

Output:

```
   Name    Year insurance Net_profit Risk_attitude Acreage_ha Adoption
   <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl>      <int> <chr>              <dbl> <chr>   
 1 Guyle   2014       158       2970 NA                  NA   NA      
 2 Guyle   2015       169       2798 NA                  NA   NA      
 3 Guyle   2016       221       2769 averse              17.6 late    
 4 Guyle   2017        NA       2686 NA                  NA   NA      
 5 Guyle   2018       200       2806 NA                  NA   NA      
 6 Porter  2014       154       3096 NA                  NA   NA      
 7 Porter  2015       185       2776 NA                  NA   NA      
 8 Porter  2016        NA       2993 seeking             26   middle  
 9 Porter  2017       450       2829 NA                  NA   NA      
10 Porter  2018       101       3090 NA                  NA   NA      
11 Frank   2014       160       2536 NA                  NA   NA      
12 Frank   2015        NA       2604 NA                  NA   NA      
13 Frank   2016        NA       2984 seeking             12   early   
14 Frank   2017       691       2881 NA                  NA   NA      
15 Frank   2018       321       3100 NA                  NA   NA
```

Comment: This is awesome. thank you all.  I would like to ask for some advice on how to learn R in the most effective. There are countless things to know but I am unsure how to systematically and effectively master it. Your advice is welcome. Thank you again

Comment: @GiftyAsare Glad it worked! Please consider checking the checkmark beside the answer that best answers your question. Among the best way to learn R is to practice - there is no quick route to mastery. There are several free online tutorials, including [Codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/catalog/language/r) or one by [Johns Hopkins University on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/jhu-data-science)

Answer (score 0):

```
list(
  dataset_1,
  insurance %>% 
    pivot_longer(-Names, names_to = "Year", values_to = "insurance", values_transform = list(insurance = as.numeric), names_transform = list(Year = as.numeric)) %>% 
    rename(Name = Names),
  dataset3
) %>% reduce(left_join)
```